# How to display List<string> of urls as hyperlinks on an ASP.Net page (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a list of strings where by each string is a url to a pdf document.  All I want to do is cycle through this list and display each url as a hyperlink on my page.  I've seen this done before in MVC where the collection is made avaliable to the view and you can just do a foreach etc etc but I don't know how to do it on a normal asp.net page...

Any help appreciated, cheers!

Comment: How do you want them displayed (table, bulleted list, comma seperated paragraph form, etc.)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could create the links using an ASP repeater on the page and bind your List to it.

Page:

```
<asp:Repeater id="repLinks" runat="server">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Container.DataItem.ToString() %>' Text="LinkText" />
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Code-behind:

```
List<string> lLinks = new List<string>();

//Define your list contents here

repLinks.DataSource = lLinks;
repLinks.DataBind();
```

Something like that should do the trick.

Comment: Yeah, I just realised I'd forgotten to add the "runat" attributes to both the repeater and the hyperlink.  Added now, cheers!

Answer (score 3):

```
<%
foreach(var url in Urls)
{
    %><a href="<%=url%>"><%=url%></a><%
}
%>
```